# Which mirror did I download the Arch Linux package database from?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman

It seems that some packages in the official package repository have a new dependency which is not in the official repos:

```
$ sudo pacman --sync --refresh --refresh --sysupgrade
:: Synchronising package databases...
 core       122.3 KiB   284K/s 00:00 [###] 100%
 extra     1773.8 KiB  2.45M/s 00:01 [###] 100%
 community    3.4 MiB  2.64M/s 00:01 [###] 100%
 multilib   163.1 KiB   426K/s 00:00 [###] 100%
:: Starting full system upgrade...
resolving dependencies...
warning: cannot resolve "ffmpeg2.8", a dependency of "firefox"
warning: cannot resolve "ffmpeg2.8", a dependency of "gst-libav"
warning: cannot resolve "ffmpeg2.8", a dependency of "vlc"
:: The following packages cannot be upgraded due to unresolvable dependencies:
      firefox  gst-libav  vlc
```

I suspect the issue might be that the mirror hasn't updated properly, so how do I figure out which one I've downloaded from?

---

This is not about how to resolve the issue once the mirror is up to date. Another refresh fixed that just fine. But this is the first time this has happened, and I'd like to avoid mirrors which get updated only partially.

Comment: AFAIAA, there is no way to determine which mirror was used for a specific package as pacman will cycle through them (unless you only have one uncommented in your mirror list). You can use a tool like [Reflector](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Reflector) to ensure you only use up-to-date mirrors.

Comment: Some reading: [Mirrors](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mirrors)